# How can i respond to tweets with images with tweepy and python bot?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

i'am using tweepy and i dont reach to tweet with an image in my response. When i run my code the console says "tweepy.errors.HTTPException: 413 Payload Too Large"
Is anyone can help ! thanks

[The console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1gAk.png)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from msilib.schema import Media
from urllib import response
import tweepy, random
import time
import pickle

##########################################################################################
CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"                                              #
CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"                                           #
ACCESS_TOKEN = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"                                              #
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"                                       #
##########################################################################################

processed_tweets = []

try:
   with open('twts.pkl', 'rb') as f:
      processed_tweets=pickle.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
   pass

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
 
twt = api.search_tweets("#NFT",result_type="Drop",count=1) 
 
for s in twt:
   if s.id not in processed_tweets:
      time.sleep(3)
      sn = s.user.screen_name
      m = "@%s " %sn + random.choice(open('tweets.txt').readlines()).strip("\n") 
      media = api.media_upload("devil.png")
   

post_result = api.update_status(status=m, media_ids=[media.media_id], in_reply_to_status_id = s.id)
processed_tweets.append(s.id)
print(s.id)

with open('twts.pkl', 'wb') as f:
   pickle.dump(processed_tweets, f)
print("Done replying!")
```

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace and all other pertinent debugging information in the body of your question as text, as prescribed by [ask]

Comment: thanks for your answer, i've added the console log

Comment: This code is written in Python. Why do you expect the Node.js interpreter to be able to execute it...? It's a completely different language.

Comment: Because i'm used to node.js.... I've tried again with python bot.py but dosent work either. I've updated the console

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly isn't clear to you about this new error? The payload you're sending is too large by the API's standards. However, it should not be possible for the code you've provided here to throw such an error, as there isn't any reference to the `.gif` file the error cites. Can you please ensure that the code here is reflective of what you're *actually* trying to use in practice, and that it conforms to our standards of creating a [mre]? How large is the `.gif` file you're attempting to send to the API service? Have you verified that it's within the limits set by Twitter?